# How to write unit tests for a method that reads csv file with papaparse in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a typescript code of this nature:

```
import * as Papa from 'papaparse'

parseCsv(file: File) {
   Papa.parse(file, {
   header: true,
   skipEmptyLines: true,
   complete: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished:", results.data);
     }
   });
}
```

How to I write a unit test for this method? I tried using a blob to mock a csv file but that didn't work. Any other way to go about it?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: have you tried to create a spy for the parse method ??

Comment: @Johnson Durant did you find any solution ?